# Can't open the image in the browser after uploading to the local server

Tags: node.js, upload, express

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
        fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
            var newPath = __dirname + '/../public/uploads/' + req.files.displayImage.name;
            console.log(newPath);
            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                    AM.savePhotogeo({
                        file : req.files.displayImage.name,
                        lat : req.param('lat'),
                        lon : req.param('lon'),
                        text : req.param('text'),
                        user : req.param('user')
                    }, function(e){
                        if (e) {
                            console.log("can't save photo geo");
                        };
                    });
                    res.redirect("/");
                };

            });
        });
    });
```

If I navigate to the folder, I can open the image with any image viewer, but if I type it in the browser's address bar like: http://localhost.com:8080/public/uploads/apple.png, it's won't open the image, but if I copy the image file to some place and then copy back to uploads/, now I can open it. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the file permissions? Who's the owner of the original and what permissions are different?

Comment: I think the owner if me. Because I uploaded the file to the uploads/ folder and I can see the image in that folder, but If I type in the image's path in the browser, I can't open it.

Comment: the owner should be system or some variant for uploads, and you for the copied file. That's the only thing that should change if you copy it and move it back.

Comment: I just figured out. I didn't require bodyParser.